# How does Buddhism explain the creation of everything (universe)

Tags: belief

How does Buddhism explain the creation of everything (universe). Did Buddhism faithfuls believe that universe had always been here and forever, and everything runs by cause-and-effect?

Did Buddha have any power of any kind to influence the universe, or it's just teaching? and if so, who rules the universe before Buddha's birth?

Comment: The Buddha is omniscient. Not almighty. There's no ruler to the universe.

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille how can you say Buddha is omniscient? does he knew everything everywhere, it make no sense for human mind, since Buddha is humain

Comment: The omniscience talked about with regards to the Buddha is different from what you think. Omniscience here doesn't mean that he sees, feels, hears everything that happens in the universe at all times. Omniscience here means that nothing is covered to him. ex: if he wants to see what is happening in another galaxy, he can see without any obstruction and he completely comprehends what he sees. This ability is described by 2 of the 6 special powers only a Buddha can attain. They are called the "Saya Asadarana Nana". The Buddha is not just a human: http://www.tbsa.org/articles/BuddhaQualities.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Buddhism says that the world has no discernible beginning.

That it runs by cause-and-effect.

That people are able to influence their own state, and have an effect on others.

And that you shouldn't spend too much attention on theoretical questions, such as "when did the universe begin?", because there are more important questions such as "how can we help to end suffering?"

Answer (score 3):

Buddhism does have an aspect of [cosmology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_cosmology_of_the_Theravada_school), [creation and evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_and_evolution) of [life on earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agga%C3%B1%C3%B1a_Sutta).

But again as @ChrisW mentioned investigating this is not:

- profitable for oneself
- profitable for others

(Unless of course you do this for a living.)

When there are worst problems to worry about like emotional imbalances and stress we go through in daily life.

Answer (score 1):

Buddha himself questions the existence and non-existence of everthing in space. That everything is unborned. Thus to him there is no creation in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think it boils down to definition and our observation time based leads to subject and object in that sequence or simultaneously but is a measure from discussion subject to timely constrained  observation our minds have. Causality in our observation has sequence answer me this if there was no time how could causality lead to creation because action and it's reaction depend upon time the only way creation could be from action is an immutable nature to time that allows the effect of causality.